# Combine Partial Classes with Normal Classes

Tags: c#, partial-classes

Is it possible to combine a normal class with a partial class like this:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public string PropertyA {get; set;}
}

public partial class ClassA
{
    public string PropertyB {get; set;}
}
```

The result of the code should look:

```
var instance = new ClassA();

instance.PropertyA = "Something";
instance.PropertyB = "Something else";
```

Does C# support this pattern?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Well did you try writing this code ?

Comment: I did, and it didn't work. So I am hoping if there is something that I'm missing or any other alternatives to achieve the same outcome? Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. All parts of a partial class have to include the `partial` modifier. From section 10.2 of the C# 4 language specification:

> **Each part of a partial type declaration must include a partial modifier.** It must have the same name  and be declared in the same namespace or type declaration as the other parts. The partial modifier indicates that additional parts of the type declaration may exist elsewhere, but the existence of such additional parts is not a requirement; it is valid for a type with a single declaration to include the partial modifier.
>
> All parts of a partial type must be compiled together such that the parts can be merged at compile-time into a single type declaration. Partial types specifically do not allow already compiled types to be extended.

(Emphasis mine.)

Comment: Thanks, I hope the future version of C# will support something similar to what I have asked in the original question.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: **No.** The MSDN states [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

> All the parts must use the partial keyword. All of the parts must be available at compile time to form the final type. All the parts must have the same accessibility, such as public, private, and so on.

Comment: It's unfortunate that MSDN explicitly calls it a keyword, when the language specification says (in the second paragraph of section 10.2) that it's *not* a keyword :(

Answer (score 0):

All files partaking in `partial` on a class must be define the class with `partial`. Furthermore, they must exist in the same assembly.

You could use polymorphism to extend ClassA. There are also extension methods, but as the name states, you can only extend methods.

Here is derivative class, although its not at all the same as `partial`.

```
public class ClassA
{

    public string PropertyA { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB : ClassA
{
    public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Did you meant to say `public class ClassB : ClassA`?